# TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment in web application

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to develop an application which can download videos and sound tracks from Youtube, but sometimes it pops out the TypeError shown by the link after making a query like "harry potter" or "lord of the rings". 
[TypeError Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZabk.png)

And here is my python code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import youtube_dl

def find_search_content(search):
    request = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}".format(search))
    content = request.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    return soup


def find_page_content(search):
    request = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?{}".format(search))
    content = request.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    return soup

def find_video(soup, all_item, i=1):
    for element in soup.find_all('a', {"rel": "spf-prefetch"}):
        video_title = element.get('title')
        video_link = element.get('href')
        img_value = element.get('href').split("=")[1]
        img = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{}/hqdefault.jpg".format(img_value)
        all_item['{}'.format(i)] = {"title": video_title, "link": "https://www.youtube.com{}".format(video_link),
                                'img': img}
        i += 1
    return all_item


def video_time(soup, all_item, i=1):
    for time in soup.find_all('span', {"class": "video-time"}):
        all_item.get('{}'.format(i))['time'] = time.text
        i += 1
    return all_item


def every_video(soup):
    all_item = {}
    find_video(soup, all_item, i=1)
    video_time(soup, all_item, i=1)
    return all_item
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `all_item.get('{}'.format(i))` is `None`, meaning that `'{}'.format(i)` is not a key present in `all_item`.

Comment: You need to handle the case where `all_item.get('{}'.format(i))` returns `None`

Comment: Also the code you've posted here doesn't correspond to the traceback. The traceback shows two different files, with functions `result_page` and `find_videoMessage`. Where are those?

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your reply! I've just updated the image link in my question.

Comment: Hi juanpa, thank you for your reply! This TypeError issue sometimes happens after the first time I make a query, while sometimes it happens when I'm trying to navigate to another result page. Theoretically the all_item dictionary cannot be empty.

Comment: It's not about being empty, just that that particular key is missing. Just `print(all_item)` and you can see exactly what it contains.

Comment: Thank you guys, it seems that sometimes the for-loop in the find-video function is executed not as many times as that of video-time function, and that can cause the TypeError problem.